# Can I form arrays for only cells with calculated data, and disregard cells with no data and just underlying formulas?

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible to only form arrays with text inside cells instead of looping through empty cells with formulas embedded?

For example I have a script that gathers the UBound's of both dimensions, but it also loops through the cells with no calculated data (appearing empty). This causes the run-time to increase a lot as I have formulas embedded to span 1000 columns and 62 rows.

How could I tell this script to only form an array with cells that have calculated text and to ignore any visibly empty cells with formulas embedded?

```
Option Explicit

Sub Main()
  Dim wb As Workbook
  Dim Data, Last, JobFamily
  Dim sourcerow As Long, destcol As Long, sourcecol As Long, destrow As Long
  Dim Dest As Range
  Dim BASEPATH As String

  Dim sPath, sFile As String

  BASEPATH = "M:\Combine\"

  sPath = "M:\VBA\"
  sFile = sPath & "Book2.xlsx"

  Set wb = Workbooks.Open(sFile)
  Set Dest = wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1")
  With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Profiles")
    Data = .Range("B1", .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))
  End With
  wb.Activate
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  For sourcecol = 1 To UBound(Data, 2)
    If Data(1, sourcecol) <> Last Then
      If sourcecol > 1 Then
        Dest.Select
          wb.SaveCopyAs BASEPATH & _
          ValidFileName(Last & ".xlsx")
      End If

      Dest.Resize(, Columns.Count - Dest.Column).EntireColumn.ClearContents
      Last = Data(1, sourcecol)
      destcol = 0
    End If

    destrow = 0
    For sourcerow = 1 To UBound(Data)
      Dest.Offset(destrow, destcol) = Data(sourcerow, sourcecol)
      destrow = destrow + 1
    Next

    destcol = destcol + 1
  Next
End Sub
```

Comment: What exactly does your spreadsheet look like? Is the data with values in a rectangle, or is it mixed in with the blank cells??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use the SpecialCells method of the Range object. Here's a small self contained demo. More info here [SpecialCells](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.specialcells)

```
Private Sub BuildConstantRange()
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        .Cells(1, 1).Value = "1"
        .Cells(2, 1).Value = "2"
        .Cells(3, 1).Value = "=if(1=1,1,0)"
        .Cells(4, 1).Value = "=if(1=1,1,0)"
        .Cells(5, 1).Value = "3"

        Dim rng As Range: Set rng = .Range("A1:A5").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
        Dim cell As Range

        For Each cell In rng
            Debug.Print cell.Address
        Next
    End With

End Sub
```

Output is:

```
$A$1
$A$2
$A$5
```

Which are the cells that do not have a formula.

Comment: So would this be thing I run before forming the array? I would just map it as is: `Range("A1:ALM62").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)`?

Comment: Should be. Something like `myArray = Range("A1:ALM62").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).value` should give you the array right away.

Comment: The array is called `Data`, so should I replace that range object with this dynamic mapping: `Data = .Range("B1", .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))
`?

Comment: Still need to add on the SpecialCells portion. Something like (untested) `Data = .Range("B1", .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).value`

Comment: Will test this tomorrow morning, I appreciate your help!!

Comment: Ok so Sorry for the super delayed response, but this celltype is only pulling in the array values. in the formula sheet. The array values are in row 2, and rows 1 & 3-62 have all of the formulas. The constants cell type only takes in the actual values from row 2 and not the values populated by the formulas. Do these need to be pasted as values for this to work?